# Cleanup /var/run full of systemd sessions

Tags: centos7, filesystems, systemd

I'm running on a quite small server (2GB RAM) where the `/var/run` mount is 950MB and a quite long uptime (~600 days).

I realized that `/var/run` is full now:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  9.9G  8.3G  55% /
devtmpfs        985M     0  985M   0% /dev
tmpfs           985M     0  985M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           985M  985M     0 100% /run
```

And investigating more with `ncdu` I realized that basically 95% of the occupied space is from `systemd` sessions.

Can I clean up without requiring a reboot? How did this happen? Is there something misconfigured somewhere?

I'm on Centos 7.4

Comment: Using `loginctl` I realized I had several sessions that were not cleared up after logout... Interesting.

Comment: 600 days uptime and CentOS 7.4? That means you forgot to reboot, at least several times. You should do that as soon as possible.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your comment. I rebooted, that clearly cleant up all the sessions. I will work on setting up a reboot schedule and check why it was not doing it.

Comment: It seems by the way to be a bug: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=14278

Answer (score 2):

hope this help:

> this command may be kill the processes under the session scope, so be
>   careful to use this command
>
> ```
> systemctl | grep "abandoned" | grep -e "-[[:digit:]]" | sed "s/.scope.*/.scope/" | xargs -r systemctl stop
> ```

ref:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1961#issuecomment-309335320

Comment: That didn't work for me, but this did:
`systemctl | grep "abandoned" | cut -f3 -d ' ' | xargs systemtctl stop`